# build step 0 "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper:latest" failed: exit status 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, deployment, migration, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a rails app to Google Cloud for the first time. Decided to give this a try over heroku. Well, when trying to do the bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:migrate it starts the migrations but then exits with this error: ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper:latest" failed: exit status 1

here's what my database.yml looks like:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

production:
  <<: *default
  database: postgres
  username: won't show
  password: won't show
  host: /cloudsql/books4reviews:us-central1:postgres-instance
```

my app.yaml:

```
entrypoint: bundle exec rackup --port $PORT
env: flex
runtime: ruby

env_variables:
  SECRET_KEY_BASE: [secret_key_base]

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: books4reviews:us-central1:postgres-instance
```

If there's anything else that would be helpful to include, let me know!

Comment: I'm familiar with App Engine but not Ruby|Rails. See the link. You need to include the `POSTGRES_[X]` environment variables in your app.yaml to be able to connect to the proxy to the PostgreSQL instance. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/using-cloud-sql-postgres

Comment: okay, I'll give that a shot. The number of steps to delpoy to app engine for a ruby on rails app is kinda ridiculous but I wanted to try it since heroku requires a paid dyno if you want your site to have an ssl. I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: @DazWikin, that worked, putting those environment variables in the app.yaml. Thanks! Greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Pleased to hear it. In App Engine's defense, I'm confident the additional configuration is a consequence of extra flexibility but, if you feel there's redundancy there, please submit feedback through the issue tracker (link at end). If you document the differences in a repro, I'm confident my Engineering colleagues will be interested in it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187250&template=1162927

Comment: I was able to deploy another ruby on rails project to gcloud with less difficulty. I'm tempted to build a document for the steps to have it all in one place rather than jumping around from one google how-to to another.

Comment: That'd be super. Perhaps blog it so others can benefit too?